# Export PDF or Excel in Mozilla by datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, datatable

I am using export functionality by datatable. This is working in Chrome. But when exporting by Mozilla browser **"[object Object]"** error coming.

This is the error, when click on export in Mozilla browser:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A Example for what you want, using the API datatable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table_id').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```css
/*
 * Table
 */
table.dataTable {
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}

table.dataTable thead th {
    padding: 3px 18px 3px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    *cursor: hand;
}

table.dataTable tfoot th {
    padding: 3px 18px 3px 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

table.dataTable td {
    padding: 3px 10px;
}

table.dataTable td.center,
table.dataTable td.dataTables_empty {
    text-align: center;
}

table.dataTable tr.odd { background-color: #E2E4FF; }
table.dataTable tr.even { background-color: white; }

table.dataTable tr.odd td.sorting_1 { background-color: #D3D6FF; }
table.dataTable tr.odd td.sorting_2 { background-color: #DADCFF; }
table.dataTable tr.odd td.sorting_3 { background-color: #E0E2FF; }
table.dataTable tr.even td.sorting_1 { background-color: #EAEBFF; }
table.dataTable tr.even td.sorting_2 { background-color: #F2F3FF; }
table.dataTable tr.even td.sorting_3 { background-color: #F9F9FF; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src= "https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>
<div>
<table id="table_id">   
        <thead>        
            <tr>            
                <th>Name</th>         
                <th>Age</th>               
                <th>Bot</th> 
            </tr>   
        </thead> 
        <tbody>  
            <tr>       
                <td>John</td>
                <td>25</td>   
                <td><button type="button" id="myBtn_1">Select</button></td> 
                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ana</td>
                <td>22</td>     
                <td><button type="button" id="myBtn_2">Select</button></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Diana</td>
                <td>23</td>    
                <td><button type="button" id="myBtn_3">Select</button></td> 
           </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>Lino</td>
                <td>32</td>    
                <td><button type="button" id="myBtn_4">Select</button></td> 
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Important notes:

Some of the features may not work in the snippet (Print);

Initializations are required, without them the code does not work.

For more information visit this link: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

Any doubt, just ask for my help.

Comment: This is not working in my application. I am exporting the excel by given way:<li>
                                    <a href="javascript:$('.buttons-excel').click();">
                                        <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> EXCEL
                                    </a>
                                </li>

Comment: This is not working in my application. I am exporting the excel by given way:    <li>    <a href="javascript:$('.buttons-excel').click();"> EXCEL  </a></li>//Bind the Accepted Escroll Files Details ( Datatable)function EscrollAcceptedFiles(FileType) {   $("#tblEscrollFileDetails").DataTable({        "processing": true,   "stateSave": true,// It is use for persist the data per aging  bsort: true,  "dom": 'lBfrtip', buttons: [{ extend: 'excelHtml5',title: 'Accepted' + " " + FileType + " " + 'Files',  }, { extend: 'pdfHtml5',  title: 'Accepted' + " " + FileType + " " + 'Files', },] });}

Comment: Did you use the datatable inisalizations? If you do not use the above version of the API https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js the application does not work. To be sure that it works you must use the latest versions that are available for the datatables.

Comment: I have added this. In moz and IE11 export is not working. If your functionality is working by my way or I want, Please post the answer. Basically I want to export file by html button not js button. Thanks for your reply